# PUTTY is not connecting

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, putty

Hi I am tying to connect my local machine to Azure Linux (ubuntu 18.04) VM using PUTTY but it gives below error

[image]

I am referring to the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-dev-start-howto-ssh-public-key?view=azs-2008#connect-with-ssh-by-using-putty

Answer (score 1):

Are you not able to ssh only while using the putty? Can you connect by using any other way?
Error message what you posted above looks very general and the root cause for this issue could be anything.

Please, check [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204400/ssh-public-key-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publ) post on Ubuntu. [There is](https://medium.com/@omar.merghany95/how-to-solve-disconnected-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publickey-eb012ffbd159) a nice article, please review it. The only difference, it's about the EC2 instances, but nature the same:

> This error can occur under the following circumstances:
>
> - You’re not connecting with the appropriate user name for your AMI
>   when you negotiate an SSH session with a VM.
> - You’re using the wrong
>   private key when you negotiate an SSH session with a VM.

Comment: I am able to connect by generating a key from .pem file rather than generate a new key.